# Choice Statement goes inside wrong IF statements

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I have this code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ZOOM_LEVEL=100
choice /c XSM /m "Please input selected font size: "
echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
    echo Font size selected: Extra Small
    set ZOOM_LEVEL=-1.5
    echo zoom1 !ZOOM_LEVEL!
) 
if %errorlevel% == 2 (
    echo Font size selected: Small
    set ZOOM_LEVEL=-1
    echo zoom2 !ZOOM_LEVEL!
)
if %errorlevel% == 3 (
    echo Font size selected: Medium
    set ZOOM_LEVEL=0
    echo zoom3 !ZOOM_LEVEL!
)
echo zoom level !ZOOM_LEVEL!
echo Font size saved

pause
```

So I am expecting that if:

- `X` is selected, ZOOM_LEVEL = -1.5
- `S` is selected, ZOOM_LEVEL = -1
- `M` is selected, ZOOM_LEVEL = 0

However, when I run this bat file I get the ff:

- `x` selected:

```
Please input selected font size: [X,S,M]?X
errorlevel: 1
Font size selected: Extra Small
zoom1 -1.5
zoom3 0
zoom level 0
Font size saved
```

- `s` selected:

```
Please input selected font size: [X,S,M]?S
errorlevel: 2
Font size selected: Small
zoom2 -1
zoom3 0
zoom level 0
Font size saved
```

- `m` selected:

```
Please input selected font size: [X,S,M]?M
errorlevel: 3
Font size selected: Medium
zoom3 0
zoom level 0
Font size saved
```

Whatever the choice is, it seems to always go to errorlevel3 since it prints `zoom3 0` but never prints `Font size selected` part.

What is happening??
Help pls. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work now using a different solution:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ZOOM_LEVEL=100
choice /c XSM /m "Please input selected font size: "
echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
set SELECTED=%errorlevel%
if %SELECTED% == 1 set ZOOM_LEVEL=-1.5
if %SELECTED% == 2 set ZOOM_LEVEL=-1
if %SELECTED% == 3 set ZOOM_LEVEL=0

echo zoomlevel %ZOOM_LEVEL%
pause
```

(But I still do not understand why the code in my question above does not work).

Thanks everyone.

Comment: As I said, your original code is working fine for me. I can imagine two reasons it didn't work for you: either the code is within a code block, which would need `!errorlevel!` (you already said that's not the case) or you defined a variable `errorlevel` which overwrote the system variable.

Comment: I honestly find it weird that it isnt working on my case. I've read my code again and again and I suppose it should work as it does on your end.  I guess it has something to do with what was mentioned here: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php about Windows NT (but I am on Windows 10).. His example doesn't work on my machine as well. Only the one inside his Windows NT note work well on my machine

Comment: I'm also on WIN10, so that's not the reason. If you get correct results after a reboot, you simply messed up something (happens even to the best of us). If it's still wrong, you should worry. Your original code should run ok on every Windows.